# discard all changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I clicked to discard all changes in vscode and all my files were deleted from desktop. How can I recover my files?

Comment: On an unrelated note, we all go through this sometime in our life. This is how we learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if the changes were uncommitted the changes are not stored in git so you cannot retrieve them. You can once check in your recycle bin, if the files are still open in vs code, you can keep hitting Ctrl+Z or Command+Z.